# how many sequence can be created in oracle...?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

how many sequence can be created in oracle.Is there any limitation on creating sequence and maximum number of sequence per table..

Comment: You can create any number of sequences.. just like every other object. Sequences are not associated with table. only programmatically we associate it with. Only Oracle12c has auto increment key.. which implicitly uses sequences and it is specific to that particular table.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21872886/how-to-revert-old-plsql

Comment: do you have any concerns with my answer?? !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316765/mysql-how-to-load-a-table-into-memory-for-fast-retrival?noredirect=1#comment33950177_22316765

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23348538/i-need-event-scheduler-for-oracle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create any number of sequences.. just like every other object. Sequences are not associated with table. only programmatically we associate it with.

But Oracle 12c has [auto increment key](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17209/statements_7002.htm#CJAIJGEG)..( value of column increments automatically for every insert) which *implicitly* uses sequences and it is specific to that particular table. And still other *explicitly* defined `sequences` are independent to the table, we use for in a `TRIGGER` or through a `PL/SQL`

You can look for the available sequences by,

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_OBJECTS WHERE OBJECT_TYPE='SEQUENCE';
```