# How to revert old plsql?

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

yesterday i altered a procedure "MAIL_INSERT_CRON".
but now i want my old procedure back..
It is possible to retrive old content of my procedure ?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot recover your procedure, until you maintain a code version for yourself.. It is same in evry other programming language. Once you deploy newer code, the old is gone for ever.

Comment: Only for this reason, code deployment should not be made directly from local file system. But by referring it from the code versioning system. Sometime DBA would take back up (every night)of all procedures and packages in a SCHEMA by their own scripts, to avoid situations like this.(mainly in production)

Comment: select text from dba_source as of TIMESTAMP (SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '1' DAY) where  name = upper('MAIL_INSERT_CRON')


ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01555: snapshot too old: rollback segment number 6 with name
"_SYSSMU6_2897970769$" too small

Comment: You have FLASHBACK enabled?

Comment: donno how to check it is enabled or not...

Comment: _select
    flashback_on 
from
    dba_tablespaces;_ What does it tell all 'N' ?

Comment: select flashback_on from dba_tablespaces;   ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "FLASHBACK_ON": invalid identifier

Comment: _SELECT flashback_on, log_mode
FROM v$database;_

Comment: So .. not enabled! Unix valiya you run? file back up illaya?

Comment: Having file backup.. bt in future i want to know how to rollback my old procedure.. if u know plz let me know

Comment: Even if FLASHBACK is enabled, I dont think we can rollback. So dont rely on the database for backup.

Comment: That's one of the many reasons, source should be stored in a version control system like Subversion or Git. And deployments should always be done by scripts coming from that version control systems.

Comment: but some other people said its possible to retrive the old procedure content

Comment: Simple answer would be- Get your old code and compile it. You should have maintained the old version of code somewhere (preferably in a version control tool)..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316765/mysql-how-to-load-a-table-into-memory-for-fast-retrival

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can recover the code from the view `all_source` if:

- you have flashback on,
- you have the privilege to use flashback on data dictionary views (which is granted by the `SELECT_CATALOG_ROLE` role),
- the data is still in the flashback area.

It seems you don't have flashback on, or the data has been overwritten already. In that case you'll have to fallback to regular lost data retrieval:

- you can restore a backup from before the drop,
- you can use [LogMiner](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16655_01/server.121/e17639/logminer.htm) to analyze your redo log files.

Comment: LogMiner, will read redo logs.. will the procedure code be tracked?

Comment: @oracleuser The logs contain both redo and undo. The data dictionary is protected by redo/undo so I don't see why it would not be tracked.

Comment: well i guess that's correct too. But chances are that he doesn't have the redo logs as well, or they might already have been written into H/w tapes shipped a 100 miles down south. :)

Comment: @Annjawn that's not a technical problem, I can't help with that :)

Comment: @VincentMalgrat I agree.

Comment: Actually i don't have much knowledge about oracle, just having 2 months experiance . so i didnt get about LogMiner concept..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22316765/mysql-how-to-load-a-table-into-memory-for-fast-retrival